# I am trying to output HTML form data to one of a few options

Tags: php, html

What I have is a selection of form boxes on a .html page that I want to output the data in any of the following ways:

To a webpage so that I can then create a "print" dialog and utilize "cutepdf" to save as a pdf.

To a PDF outright (preferable if possible/semi-simple)

To even a .txt file (least preferred method)

I have a workaround of printing the screen with the form data currently up, but this leaves the form boxes there, which i'd like to avoid.

I've tried several php scripts i've found, some javascript stuff, and i'm just at a loss as to where to go next.

My current code is:
    
    Customer Info Form

```
 <form>
 <b>Primary Purchaser</b><br>
First name:
<input size="35" type="text" name="firstname">
Last name:
<input size="38" type="text" name="lastname">
<br>


<form name="Submit" action="signup.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Save and Submit">
</form>
<!<form action="submit.php">
<!<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<!</form> 
</HTML>
```

and my php is currently:

```
<?php
print 'firstname'
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
?>
```

I have no idea where to go from here.  I'mn not even 100% sure I want to use php.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not clear. Are you trying to print a receipt or have the user save the results of signing up? Need some more info here, like what errors are you getting?

Comment: your question is very unclear, you should clarify it so we will understand you. please try to explain briefly what is it that you are trying to achieve

Comment: this is a very broad question. all of your desired results are possible, but require work/research on your part to accomplish them. But first, your html is invalid, as (1) you have inputs above/before the `<form>` tag, (2) you have 2 forms/submit buttons with no other inputs.

Comment: Ok, basically I am trying to get the form data to a human readable file.  I really had no idea where to go with this when I started and i'm no programmer by any means.  I work in IT and don't touch code/script enough to reasonably work this out myself.

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes in your code. This is how it should be done if you want to get the input values that you typed when an user hit `Submit` button.

```
<b>Primary Purchaser</b>
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
First name: <input size="35" type="text" name="firstname">
Last name: <input size="38" type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You should have `submit.php` that handles when the form has been submitted. You change change to whatever you want but you should mention that file name with extension in `action`. (i.e `<form action="here"`)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    echo $firstname . "<br/>";
    echo $lastname;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'm finally getting the "php" page that wasn't showing up before, but now i'm getting 

""; echo $lastname; } ?>"    output on the php page.  I don't know why it's not reading that last bit of syntax.

Comment: No, it does not.  nothing except that syntax outputs.

Comment: Can you upload your html file code and php code in pastebin.com?

Comment: @user3132706 are you saving the file with .php?

Comment: @user3132706 Ok. Just do what i say. Create a new file test.php and copy paste this code. Open this file in browser http://pastebin.com/jY1Phe56

Comment: http://imgur.com/02bMzOc  Still getting this output.  syntax shows up after and before submit

Comment: @user3132706 Man, you should not run php file in documents like html file. Php file to be parsed. For windows, get `Xampp` and install first. Then start the Apache and put this file in htdocs folder inside of Xampp. It will be located at C:\Xampp\htdocs\. You really need to start learn php from basic. Visit W3schools.com and choose Php. They will guide you from the beginning how to install the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using http://phptopdf.com/

Modify your PHP to something like this :

```
<?php
require('phpToPDF.php');

if(isset($_POST)) //Check if the user submitted the data we need. 
{
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

//Your HTML in a variable
$my_html="<HTML><h2>Firstname</h2><br>".$firstname."<br>".$lastname."</HTML>";

//Set Your Options -- we are saving the PDF as 'my_filename.pdf' to a 'my_pdfs' folder
$pdf_options = array(
  "source_type" => 'html',
  "source" => $my_html,
  "action" => 'save',
  "save_directory" => 'my_pdfs',
  "file_name" => 'my_filename.pdf');

//Code to generate PDF file from options above
phptopdf($pdf_options);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my modules creates an HTML page that I optionally convert to a PDF. I use the program wkhtmltopdf and call it from my Python code (running under Linux) with the line:-

```
os.system('wkhtmltopdf -q --page-width 230 --page-height 330 "%s" "%s"' % (filePath, pdfFilePath))
```

Hope this helps.